# Inner Join with Date offset from one another table.

Tags: mysql, date

My database consists of a set of users that have birthdates. (Millions)

```
    |      USERS      |
    - - - - - - - - - -
    | ID | BIRTHDATE  |
    | 1  | 1987-12-14 | 
    | 2  | 1984-12-19 |
    | 3  | 1987-12-14 |
    | 4  | 1987-12-16 |
```

No we have a mechanism in which we can create groups. Groups of users that are X days to their birthday. (For marketing purposed).

```
    |      GROUPS     |
    - - - - - - - - - -
    | ID | BIRTHDATE_OFFSET  |
    | 1  | 2                 | 
    | 2  | -2                |
    | 3  | 4                 |
    | 4  | 17                |
```

How do I find all the customers and their corresponding groups at once?

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple `JOIN` using the offset in the join criteria.

```
SELECT u.id AS user, g.id AS group
FROM USERS AS u
JOIN GROUPS AS g ON u.birthdate = date_add(curdate(), interval g.birthdate_offset DAY)
```